# Why wouldn't something be outputting to test.log from the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying the following from a controller after running the test with RSpec/Guard

```
  Rails.logger.info "My info message"
  Rails.logger.debug "My debugging message"
  Rails.logger.warn "My warning message"
```

and none of these show up in test.log. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access logger following the example.

```
RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "My info message"
```

Comment: I just tried `puts "HI THERE MY MAN"` and it didn't work. From controller can't see that in my test.log.

Comment: I see. check the current solution.

Comment: you should have a log for each environment. Are you sure to be checking the right file?